# Why there is no closure for Z

Tags: python, python-2.7

1.)Why the closure is not  generated for example 1  whereas 
    for example 2 there is closure.

2.)Example 1 Even though there is no closure for Z how I am able to get the value from outer function for  Z (As once the local function scope is over all the objects are garbage collected or retained based on closure)

**Example 1**

```
def outer():
    x=3
    y=4
    z=0
    def inner(z):
        return x,y,z
    return inner

i=outer()
i.__closure__
Out[69]: 
(<cell at 0x000000000451D738: int object at 0x0000000001D681A8>,
 <cell at 0x000000000451D408: int object at 0x0000000001D68190>)
```

output

```
i(2)
Out[78]: (3, 4, 2)
```

But when I do

**Example 2**

```
def outer():
    x=3
    y=4
    z=0
    def inner():
        return x,y,z
    return inner

i=outer()
i.__closure__
Out[72]: 
(<cell at 0x000000000451D528: int object at 0x0000000001D681A8>,
 <cell at 0x000000000451D3A8: int object at 0x0000000001D68190>,
 <cell at 0x000000000451D9A8: int object at 0x0000000001D681F0>
```

Comment: In Example 1, you shadowed the non-local `z` with a parameter by the same name.

Comment: Call your parameter to `inner` something that does not shadow `z`, like `w`. What is do you want the third output argument to be `z` or `w` in that case? Either way, it will work as coded. Not sure what is tripping you up.

Comment: Function parameters are locals too; `z` in `def inner(z):` is a local, never a closure or a global.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why the closure is not generated for example 1 whereas for example 2 there is closure.

Because the inner function doesn't need the `z` from the outer function.

> Even though there is no closure for Z how I am able to get the value from outer function for Z

You can't. The `z` you're getting is the argument you passed, not the `z` from the outer function. (That's why it's 2 instead of 0.)